# Alternative to relational DB for transactional duplicate validation processing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, duplicates

I'm currently using SSMS, working with two tables both which have millions of records; let's call them: **latest_status table** and **dupe_hash** table.

**latest_status**:

- latest_status_PK - bigint - identity(1,1)
- status - bigint

  - 50 => stage-zero
  - 100 => stage-one
  - 200 => stage-two
  - 999 => duplicate-failed

**dupe_hash**:

- dupe_hash_PK - bigint - identity(1,1)
- latest_status_FK (relationship with latest_status) - bigint
- md5 - varchar(256)
- batch_id - uniqueidentifier

My objective is to look through **dupe_hash** records (where **latest_status**.status = 100) and see if this record's **md5** is the same as another record's **md5**; I update the **latest_status.status** of the these depending on their **status**es. Something along the lines of:

*record_1's status = 100 & record_2's status = 200 => update record_1's status to 999

*record_1's status = 100 & record_2's status = 50 => update record_1's status to 200 and record_2's status to 999

I'm currently using set-based operations, saving this query into a table variable and updating the **latest_status** table with a case statement. In my partition by md5, I am ordering the subsets based on their **status** because in the end, I only want to keep one record (**rowid** = 1) and the others would be set to 999:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DUPHASH.MD5 ORDER BY CASE WHEN LATEST_STAT.STATUS = 200 THEN 0 WHEN LATEST_STAT.STATUS = 50 THEN 1 ELSE 1 END, LATEST_STAT.latest_status_PK DESC) ROWID,
 LATEST_STAT.CLAIM_OUTBOUND_LATEST_STATUS_KEY,
 LATEST_STAT.STATUS,
 DUPHASH.DUPLICATE_KEY,
 DUPHASH.BATCH_ID,
 DUPHASH.MD5
  FROM DBO.DUPE_HASH DUPHASH
 INNER JOIN DBO.LATEST_STATUS LATEST_STAT
 WHERE MD5 IN (SELECT DISTINCT MD5
             FROM DBO.DUPE_HASH DUPHASH
                INNER JOIN DBO.LATEST_STATUS LATEST_STAT
                   ON DUPHASH.LATEST_STATUS_FK = LATEST_STAT.LATEST_STATUS_PK
                WHERE STATUS = 105) ON DUPHASH.LATEST_STATUS_FK = LATEST_STAT.LATEST_STATUS_PK
```

This brings me to my actual question: Are there any alternatives/improvements to this approach that could support realtime/transactioal processing?

- table partitioning?
- non-relational DBs?

I'm really all ears. Thank you!

Comment: does select md5 from dupe_hash group by md5 having count(1) > 1 return all hashes that are duplicates for you?  The subquery in the where statement should be better off as an inner join to a table where you have identified all duplicate ones in advance.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/